# Bootstrap dropdown caret not showing in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show a caret on the right side of a bootstrap dropdown button within a button-group.

My code is (see also [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KdUdS/10/)):

```
<div class="span3 well">
    <div class="btn-group btn-block">
        <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-block" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        New &hellip; <i class="caret pull-right"></i>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.btn-group .dropdown-toggle {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

In webkit (Safari & Chrome) it looks as intended:

[image: webkit]

However Firefox does not work:

[image: gecko]

Did I make a mistake here? Which behavior is correct? What should I do to make it work everywhere?

​

Comment: If you look at it in Firebug, the `caret pull-down` is falling below the width of the `a` tag it's within.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `btn-group` was causing the problem:

```
.btn-block .dropdown-toggle {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

<div class="span3 well">
  <div class="btn-block"> <!-- <<< Right here is where I removed btn-group -->
    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-block" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
      New &hellip; <i class="caret pull-right"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/KdUdS/12/

It looks the same in Chrome as it does in Firefox.

**EDIT**

Here's the problem:

```
.btn-group {
    font-size: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;    // <<< This here
}
```

That's on [`line 3438 of bootstrap.css`](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css). I fixed it with:

```
<div class="btn-block btn-group" style="white-space: normal;">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/KdUdS/14/

Now the dropdown elements don't look so hot, but I assume you know that are going to fix that.

Comment: There's no `btn-group` on the one you marked as the answer? And that one's all over the place. I don't know what the answer is to fix that problem, but that other answer's arrow isn't particularly lined up correctly either. So I imagine there's a way to fix this and it would still be preferable.

Comment: @lucasclemente - Take another look at it. I found the problem (`white-space: nowrap`).

Comment: great, thanks a lot, that's probably the way to do it. the other answer just had to correct the css, then it was fine too, but your explanation is better ;)

Comment: The other one added markup and what markup was there, it was invalid. It was a mess. I didn't realize this wasn't working on the dropdown, otherwise I would have fixed it.

Comment: now that i look at it i don't understand why i marked it as answer ;) sorry, and thanks again!