# twitter bootstrap issue : Right align the caret in the dropdown header

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, caret

I have an issue with the right alignment of the caret. Using .pull-right in the span makes it go to the top  right corner.

How can I make it vertically centered again ?
I also would like to align the text to the left

http://www.bootply.com/r8x7g5Bw5R

```
                    <div class="btn-group cust-dropdown">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle cust-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret pull-right"></span><span>test</span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">tes2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">test3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

and the CSS

```
.cust-dropdown {
width: 200px;}
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Just interchange the caret and span blocks in HTML:

**HTML**

```
   <div class="btn-group cust-dropdown">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle cust-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><span id= "titl">test</span><span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">test 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .cust-dropdown {
        width: 200px;
    }

    #titl {

      padding-right: 10px;
    }
```

You can align the text more to the left by adding more `padding-right`.

Comment: Hi Hristo
Using a custom "padding-right" on the text works but it is not "responsive" as the width of the dropdown and the length of the text can change. Ideally I would like the text and the caret to be moved automatically to the left and the right of the dropdown (with vertical align center)

Comment: Well, if you make padding-right into percentages, it will become responsive. Eitherway, you've already set it to have 200px width, so it won't be a problem at different resolutions (you can check if you wish) . I don't understand how vertical-align: center will move the caret and the text. Perhaps you can explain more?

Comment: Hi Hristo,
I used 200px width for the example. I found a quick solution for the caret by using .caret {margin-top:8px;float:right;}

Comment: the margin-top, float-right techniques works great in IE and chrome but looks bad in firefox

Comment: this question has a fix for firefox: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657520/bootstrap-dropdown-caret-not-showing-in-firefox just add style="white-space: normal;"

Comment: @GWTF I was able to make it work using position absolute in Chrome, IE and FF.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 29):

```
.caret {
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid #fff;
    left: 90%;
    top: 45%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Using position absolute and a percentage top and left I was able to right align my caret within the dropdown.  Works in Chrome, IE, and FF.

**EDIT**

Previous code will work but changes the style of the caret. If you just want to reposition it maintaining its style, just extend Bootstrap's .caret class:

```
.caret {
    position: absolute;
    left: 90%;
    top: 45%;
}
```

Comment: This worked fine initially, but when I resize the page the caret doesn't re-evaluate the percentages, so it becomes misaligned.

Answer (score 13):

A much simpler solution exists for this problem. This style should look the most natural and be the most responsive to all usages as it does not depend on any predetermined layout (other than default bootstrap styles).

```
.dropdown > .btn > .caret {
  float: right;
  margin: 6px 0;
  // if you are using Less, the you can reuse the actual vertical padding
  // margin: @padding-base-vertical 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi @pjs, `@padding-base-vertical` doesn't work. It also gives validation error *padding-base-vertical is not a valid value for the "margin" property*. But the **6px** works fine :)

Comment: @padding-base-vertical will only work if you are using the less CSS preprocessor.

Comment: It would be better if we can find a relative margin instead of using magic number 6.

Comment: `6px` is the value of `@padding-base-vertical` that is [defined as a constant in bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/b34765d8a6aa775816c59012b2d6b30c4c66a8e9/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss#L95). the preferred method is to use the Less pre-processor and reference the constant.